# Embedding Microsoft forms in SharePoint online to show (Questions and Responses) - Classic mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow, classic-experience, microsoft-forms

I would like to use the Microsoft forms for a quick poll  on an intranet (Classic mode) and was wondering if there is a way to redirect the user to the responses page/link after a survey or poll has been submitted?
Or a way to have the questions and responses tabbed side by side?

Any resources or tips  would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way (web part) to add the Microsoft Form in SharePoint Online Classic Pages like there is one in Modern Pages, [Use the Microsoft Forms web part](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/use-the-microsoft-forms-web-part-d4b4d3ce-7860-41e4-8a98-76380efe7256).

However, you can add Microsoft Form in Classic page using **Script Editor Web Part**.

Follow below steps:

1. Create a Microsoft Form and Click on **Share** button at top right corner.
2. Select **Embed (`</>`)** and **Copy** the iframe code.
3. Go to your SharePoint Classic Page, and then **Edit page**.
4. Add **Script Editor** web part from **Media and Content** category.
5. Copy your iframe code in the Script Editor web part.
6. Save.

This will capture your responses. But there is not direct way to redirect to responses page after submitting the survey.

**Update for Modern Pages**:

**No**, On Modern pages also it will not redirect to responses after submitting the response.

But, If you want to show the responses to your end users then you can add another Microsoft forms web part for same Form and configure it as **Show form results** from property pane as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ganesh but on the Modern UI when i submit a survey or poll will it redirect to the responses?

Comment: No, On Modern pages also it will not redirect to responses after submitting the response. Check updated answer for work around.

Comment: Have you tried this? Is it working for you?

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. I do need a solution that would work in classic mode for both the questions and response pages

Comment: Welcome. I am afraid but there is no such OOTB webpart for microsoft forms to work in classic code.